# Sometimes when I turn on my computer, all I get is static on the screen

Tags: windows-8.1, hdmi, sleep, intel-graphics, intel-core-i5

I connect my computer to my TV via HDMI. When I wake up the computer (I usually only put it to sleep), and the input is already on the PC input, all is well. However, if the input is on ANY OTHER input, and I change it to the PC input after the PC is already running, all I get is static. I have to put the computer back to sleep and wake it back up to get a normal signal.

- [EVGA Z97 Stinger](http://www.evga.com/articles/00835/) Wi-Fi motherboard
- Intel HD Graphics 4600 v10.18.14.4264
- Samsung 52 inch 650 series LCD TV

Comment: like oldschool black and white static?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes :(

Comment: Some odd interaction between the display driver and TV's EDID (or equivalent) I suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one of those annoying "compatibility" issues between hardware. I'd call it a bug. You can read all about it [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2010/12/17/connecting-your-pc-to-an-hdtv-with-hdmi/).

The important stuff from the above link:

> The most common challenge we see when integrating older PCs or HD displays via HDMI has been the so-called “handshake issue.”...
>
> ...part of the HDMI specification involves a content protection scheme called HDCP (high-bandwidth digital copy protection) in which the source device checks the receiving device for an authentication key...
>
> Your graphics card may have an older driver, for instance, or the firmware for your display may be out of date.
>
> ...commonly reported symptoms... black screen when the primary video display is no longer available. For example, you’ve switched to another input, and then back to the HDMI input, or turned the TV off and left the HTPC on, or the HTPC is resuming from sleep.

Your PC is modern enough (and Intel Graphics is quite mature these days). Assuming your graphics driver is up-to-date, the most likely culprit will be your TV. You may be able to update the TV's firmware (visit/contact Samsung support with your TV's *exact* model number). Otherwise, you can just live with it knowing how to work around the issue.

Comment: Note that, even though the referenced blog entry dates back to Windows 7 days, the issue continues to exist today, with certain hardware combinations, even on Windows 8.x and 10.